# Relation between Angular Acceleration and Angular Frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

For a Simple Harmonic Oscillator, How to derive the formula:

[image]

Comment: Try to show your work, then ask a specific question about concepts. A homework-like question like this with no work shown will only get downvote.

Comment: As written there is possibly no answer to the question as the formula you quote is the definition of SHM. Are you asking about a specific system?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple harmonic oscillator the position is given by:

$$ x = A \sin(\omega t + \phi) $$

We get the velocity by differentiating this with respect to time:

$$ v = \frac{dx}{dt} = \omega A \cos(\omega t + \phi) $$

And we get the acceleration by differentiating the velocity:

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} $$

I'll leave this last step to you.